# MVVM Multiple Edit Windows

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, mvvm

Please am still new to MVVM, and am using it with Sivlerlight. I run into a scenario where I have a Main UserControl containing one DataGrid, Employees forexample. User can double click any datagrid record to Show the EditEmployeeWindow (non blocking) so users can at the same time edit more than one employee. The only problem I have is that (one of our requirements) that when the users click save on any Edit,New window the data has to be saved to the database directly, and with one model a Save operation will save all the changes.

So one of the solutions on my head is to create an EditorViewModel that has it's own Model (new Instance of the model) and take id of edited record. In the EditorViewModel I will load this single record freshly and would direclty save changes only to that record. Also to use MVVM-Light Messenger to send message to the MainViewModel to refresh it's data since it they'll not be the same anymore.

Please could you guide me! Am I on the right track?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks OK, but I strongly recommend you to store the list of editing records somewhere in the main view model to not allow multiple windows on same record. Also, as you already going to use messenger to communicate with main view model, when main v.m. will receive it's child window closed message, send message to other windows, forcing them to close, and then call refresh method on main v.m.

It actually may be a little bit tricky to identify when all windows are closed (as you do work async), there are a lot of ways to do this, but I recommend you following:

1) Track a state of the main view model (is it has opened window, waiting for all windows to close, etc)

2) When window commit operation finished notify main v.m. and remove id form the list of active records.

3) When there no more records left in the list, refresh data.

Eventually when you will have to add more logic related to popup windows, I recommend to extract popup related code to the class named something like PopupService, it should be singleton, but I strongly recommend you to get it instance through one of the IoC containers (Unity, MvvmLight one, or event MEF).

Comment: Hi,
First thank you for you quick reply and for the tips you gave.
Im going to give it a try regarding your recommendations. Honestly there are still some question on my mind but I prefere to postpone them till I do a sample, so my questions, hopefully, would be direct.

Thanks and regards